# .css() or addClass()/removeClass() Not Being Applied in Safari? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

Is there a particular reason why the script I am troubleshooting will not apply their assigned classes, or styles? I have tried different methods, (in an attempt to achieve the same result), but nothing has worked so far...

**FIRST ATTEMPT:**
Here was my initial attempt with `.toggleClass()`, (which worked in Firefox and Chrome, but did not fire at all Safari):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#pgnav');
  var div1 = $('#container2');
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    var window_top_to_div2 = ($window.height() - div2.height()) / 2;
    var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
    var div1_height = div1.height();
    var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
    div2.toggleClass('show', scrollTop >= (div1_top - window_top_to_div2) && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= (div1_bottom + window_top_to_div2));
  });
});
```

Additionally, here is an excerpt of the CSS:

```
#pgnav {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#pgnav.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

**SECOND ATTEMPT:** Then I swiched out `.toggleClass()` for `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()`, (and still no luck):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#pgnav');
  var div1 = $('#container2');
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    var window_top_to_div2 = ($window.height() - div2.height()) / 2;
    var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
    var div1_height = div1.height();
    var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
    if (scrollTop >= (div1_top - window_top_to_div2) && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= (div1_bottom + window_top_to_div2)) {
      div2.addClass('show')
    } else {
      div2.removeClass('show');
    }
  });
});
```

---

**THIRD ATTEMPT:** Finally, I attempted to use `.css()` instead of `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()`, and it still delivered no response in Safari:

```js
if (scrollTop >= (div1_top - window_top_to_div2) && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= (div1_bottom + window_top_to_div2)) {
  div2.css('display', 'inline');
} else {
  div2.css('display', 'none');
}
```

---

**FOURTH ATTEMPT:** Here's something else I've tried, based on this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11325039/9214076, (but still no luck!):

```js
if (scrollTop >= (div1_top - window_top_to_div2) && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= (div1_bottom + window_top_to_div2)) {
  div2.css('display', 'inline').parent().addClass("dummyClass").removeClass("dummyClass");
} else {
  div2.css('display', 'none').parent().addClass("dummyClass").removeClass("dummyClass");
}
```

Why won't Safari run any of these script variations? Though the task at hand seems straightforward enough, nothing seems to resolve the issue...

Also, to see a full snippet of this in action, I advise you to visit my previous post here: [Can toggleClass Work in Safari? (JQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50957582/9214076)

Comment: which version/environment. OSX/iOS/safari?

Comment: @dgeare The latest version of OSX is where I'm facing the issue.

Comment: Cleared the cache? Latests Safari have a very persistent cache.

Comment: hmmm.... There was some screwy behavior with iOS < 8 with regards to scroll events, which is why I was asking. if you `console.log(scrollTop)` do you see it update in the console as you scroll? (sorry, don't have access to an apple device)

Comment: No, I didn't see anything update.

Comment: I have cleared the cache as well.

Comment: what about if you add a vanilla JS passive scroll handler outside of all the jQuery stuff `window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ console.log(window.scrollY)}, {passive:true})` see anything in the console on scroll then?

Comment: I see that `style="display:none;"` does get added to `#pgnav`, but it never activates the switch/toggle between styles, or classes.

Comment: Resolved, answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005505/9214076. There was a complication with `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. By replacing it with `$(window).scrollTop()`, the script now runs smoothly cross-browser.